# Firebase Firestore cloud functions: filtering documents by date conditions in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I need to filter documents in Firestore by date within a cloud function using **node.js**. I'd like to return only those documents that have a timestamp (or date string) more than 30 days from the current date in a field named `last_used`. At present, not all documents have this field. One method I have thought about employing is writing a trigger function to give each document a `last_used` field and set the timestamp to 01/01/2022, run this once and then the scheduled function can update the field when required with the current date. The scheduled function currently selects a `player` document at random each day, moves the required fields into the `current-live-player` collection and updates the `last_used` field for the selected `player` document within `available-players`.

**Context**: I'm building a game in which a `player` document is selected at random each day from the `available-players` collection and placed into the `current-live-player` collection. `current-live-player` is made up of just this one document and updated each day at 00:00 London time. I only want Firestore to select a `player` document from `available-players` that meets my aforementioned condition: the date within `last_used` is more than 30 days prior to the current date.

This is what I have so far:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { firestore } = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
// Potential trigger function to give all player objects a last_used field
exports.addLastUsedToAll = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // Logic to add a last_used field with a date of 01/01/2022
});

// Select a player function that runs every day at 00:00 London time
exports.pickCurrentLivePlayer = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *")
    .timeZone("Europe/London")
    .onRun(async () => {

      // select a random player from available players (uses the auto-generated IDs)
      // ifelse catches rare cases that could cause an error
      const availablePlayers = db.collection("available-players");
      const key = availablePlayers.doc().id;
      
      availablePlayers.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '>=', key).limit(1).get()
      .then(snapshot => {
          if(snapshot.size > 0) {
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                console.log('snapshot.size > 0 ', doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                // replace live player
                const newPlayerData = doc.data();
                const app_first_name = newPlayerData.app_first_name;
                const uid = newPlayerData.uid;
                db.collection("live-player").doc("current-live-player").set({app_first_name: app_first_name, uid: uid});
                // set selected player's last_used value to current time
                db.collection("available-players").doc(uid).update({
                    last_used: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()          
                })
              });
          }
          else {
              const player = availablePlayers.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<', key).limit(1).get()
              .then(snapshot => {
                  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                      console.log('snapshot.size > 0 ', doc.id, '=>', doc.data().name);
               // replace live player
                const newPlayerData = doc.data();
                const app_first_name = newPlayerData.app_first_name;
                const uid = newPlayerData.uid;
                db.collection("live-player").doc("current-live-player").set({app_first_name: app_first_name, uid: uid});
                // set selected player's last_used value to current time
                db.collection("available-players").doc(uid).update({
                    last_used: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
                })
                  });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
              });
          }
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
      return null;
    });
```

I hope that all makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated. I know that it can be tricky to convert timestamps and then filter by date in javascript, but I'd like to use the Firestore timestamp to ensure that the functions are always running off the server time.

**Edit**:

In response to Frank van Puffelen's answer, the timestamp calculations are now working and each document in `available players` now has a `last_used` field populated with a timestamp. I now need to query `available_players` to show those documents in which the timestamp is more than 30 days ago. The issue now is that I cannot query the collection before running my random selection. The order should be: **1)** calculate today's date minus 30 days; **2)** query `available_players` for all documents with a timestamp in the `last_used` field more than 30 days in the past; **3)** generate a key from this filtered selection; **4)** query the filtered selection to give me one random document and process the rest of the update logic etc. It falls down where the filtered data is now a query snapshot rather than a collection reference and the code I have no longer runs (at least I think that's the issue!). The code worked perfectly before attempting to add this 'filter by date' functionality. I've provided a minimal repro here:

```
// calculate time interval
const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
const intervalInMillis = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const cutoffTime = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(now.toMillis() - intervalInMillis);

// get collectionReference and filter to those more than 30 days ago
const allPlayers = db.collection("available-players");
const availablePlayers = await allPlayers.where('last_used', '<=', cutoffTime).get();

// generate key
const key = availablePlayers.doc().id;

// select a random player from the filtered selection
availablePlayers.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '>=', key).limit(1).get()
      .then(snapshot => {
..etc etc
```

I somehow need to be able to query the data to filter it by date and then run the random selection chunk of code.

Comment: The use-case seems relatively clear, but what is your question for us about the code you shared?

Comment: Thanks for your response, within the pickCurrentLivePlayer function I'd like availablePlayers to be all players that meet the date condition (last_used more than 30 days ago), i.e., filter to those players (documents) rather than returning all documents. Hope that's clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the players that were last used more than 30 days ago would be something like this:

```
const availablePlayers = db.collection("available-players");
const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
const intervalInMillis = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const cutoffTime = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(now.toMillis() - intervalInMillis);

const query = availablePlayers.where(last_used, "<=", cutoffTime);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The maths is exactly what I needed! I have implemented it however my function now doesn't run. Is this because "const query" is now a query object and not a collection reference? I need to query the collection to return all documents that meet the date inclusion criteria. I then need the key constant to be created from those returned documents. Then the "availablePlayers.where ..." part of the function to run but it throws an error. I tried running it with "query.where..." but still throws errors. Any suggestions would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: You should be able to call `get()` on the query, and then use the resulting `QuerySnapshot` the same as you did for the collection already. If that doesn't work, it'd be good to see a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the new situation, either as an edit to this question or as a new question.

Comment: I have added a minimal repro of the code in it's current state (not working) for you to see. I think the issue is the fact that I am querying the collection by `document_id()` and I can't get this to work in the same way with a `QuerySnapshot` after querying to meet the date criteria.

Comment: what error are you getting? Why cant you use the `QuerySnapshot` ? weren't you already using them? this sounds like it should be a new question given it already has an accepted answer

Comment: I'm not sure why but the `availablePlayers.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), ...` line doesn't run when I put the time filtering query first. It does if I just run it without the filter. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766977/multiple-queries-on-firestore-collectionreference-and-querysnapshot-cloud-funct)